# Windows 7 - spontaneous wake from sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, logging, event-viewer

Irregularly, unattended PC wakes up.  A typical 'system' event log sequence is below   Basically, my question is whether anything can be inferred from this.  More specifically,

- Is the order of events meaningful? (The 'resumed from sleep' event comes 8
  seconds after the 'time changed' one.)
- Is it significant that the 'resumed' event says the wake source is
  the keyboard?  (Which no one is near when this happens.)

---

Event Log sequence (typical):
...

- 12:04:28 Service Control Manager   The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service
  was successfully sent a stop control.
- 7:22:16 Kernel-General   The system time has changed to
  ‎2016‎-‎02‎-‎11T12:22:16.500000000Z from ‎2016‎-‎02‎-‎11T05:04:28.050016900Z.
- 7:22:16 Service Control Manager   The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service
  entered the stopped state.
- 7:22:16 Service Control Manager   The Multimedia Class Scheduler
  service entered the stopped state.
- 7:22:19 Service Control Manager   The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service
  entered the running state.
- 7:22:21 Service Control Manager   The Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
  service entered the running state.
- 7:22:22 Service Control Manager   The Windows Error Reporting Service
  service entered the running state.
- 7:22:26 Power-Troubleshooter   The system has resumed from sleep.  Sleep Time: ‎2016‎-‎02‎-‎11T05:04:18.456000000Z; Wake Time: ‎2016‎-‎02‎-‎11T12:22:17.280001300Z; Wake Source: Device -Standard PS/2 Keyboard

Comment: The cat walked on your keyboard ;) Vibrations can cause this (although then it's more likely to be the mouse ake up call).

Answer (score 0):

Like what David said, it seems to be the keyboard that woke it. However, besides looking through the 'system' event log, running powercfg /lastwake can also provide you with some information on this issue.

One thing that I discovered that was causing my computer to wake up from sleep was scheduled tasks by Windows Media Center, which were waking the computer to get TV scheduling updates.  I had to go through Task Scheduler and find these tasks in the Media Center folder that had the option enabled to allow it to wake the computer, and disable this option on each.